# Poincare-like inequality in $H^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Assume $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ for bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, in general $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C\|D^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is not true as the trace of the function $\nabla u$ may not be $0$. However, do we have
$\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\lesssim\|D^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$?

One counter example that makes $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C\|D^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ fail to be true is $u$ is a general linear function, which means that right hand side is $0$ while the left hand side is not. Now for the second inequality, when right hand side is $0$, the left hand side has to be $0$. Can we then use an usual argument by contradiction used in the proof of Poincare inequality to prove the second inequality?

Comment: Yes, this is true, provided $u$ has zero trace (Chapter 5, Exercise 9, L.C. Evans PDE book).

Comment: Note your first inequality requires $\nabla u$ to have trace zero, not $u$. The inequality you ask for, with the L2 norm of $u$ on the right hand side, should follow from a proof by contradiction using compactness, even when $u$ is not trace zero. It would be perhaps helpful if you try this argument and let us know where you get stuck.